# Find numbers at specific positions in a string with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I need a Regex pattern which is going to be used to remove some numbers at specific positions.

My string format is like this: `xxxx - 2013-xxxxxx9 xxxxxxxx9`, the '9' in the string means a number or doesn't exist.

The code I wrote is like this:

```
  string str= "dddd - 2013-0Winter1 morning2";
  Regex pattrn = new Regex(".* - ([0-9]{4}-).*([1-9]?) .*([1-9]?)$");
  Match match = pattern.Match(me);
  for (int index = match.Groups.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
  {
    str = str.Remove(match.Groups[index].Index, match.Groups[index].Length);
  }
```

When I run this, `match.Groups[2]` and `match.Groups[3]`'s value are blank. But I want to find '`2013`','`1`' and '`2`' in the string.

The result is:

```
"dddd - 0Winter1 morning2";
```

The result I want is:

```
"dddd - 0Winter morning";
```

Does anybody know why?

Comment: You mean these are in _fixed_ positions? If so, why not use `Substring`?

Comment: If the first '9' exists, a space must be followed, if the second '9' exists, it must be at the end of the string.

Comment: That is really unclear. Can you post several examples of valid strings and expected output for each?

Comment: Agree with @Oded - the format specified is *very* unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `.*` is greedy so it's gobbling up the `([1-9]?)` that comes after it. If you use a [non-greedy quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx) (`.*?`), you'll get the result you want:

```
string str = "dddd - 2013-0Winter1 morning2";
Regex pattern = new Regex("^.* - ([0-9]{4}-).*?([1-9]?) .*?([1-9]?)$");
Match match = pattern.Match(str);
for (int index = match.Groups.Count - 1; index > 0; index--)
{
    str = str.Remove(match.Groups[index].Index, match.Groups[index].Length);
}

Console.WriteLine(str); // dddd - 0Winter morning
```

Of course, this will produce the same result:

```
string str = "dddd - 2013-0Winter1 morning2";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"^(\w*? [0-9]{4}-\w*?)[1-9]? (\w*?)[1-9]?$", "$1 $2");
Console.WriteLine(str); // dddd - 0Winter morning
```